# How to use multidimensional array in ajax json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

here i have created function for fetching two `Dimensional array`.that's working fine but here i am also inserting one row. after inserting that row that function is loading but i am not able to fetch the data.

```
function get_company_expenses_type(element_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../modal/system_operator/get_companyexpenses_type.php",
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (json) {
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            length = result.len;
            for (k = 1; k <= length; k++) {
                $('#' + element_id + ' option').last().after('<option value="' + eval("result.row" + k + ".company_expenses_type_id") + '">' + eval("result.row" + k + ".company_expenses_type") + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    var cnt = 1;
    $("#anc_add").click(function () {
        cnt++;
        $("input[id=rows]").val(cnt);
        $('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td><select name="' + cnt + '1"><option value="0">Select Expenses Type</option>X</select></td><td><textarea name="' + cnt + '2"></textarea></td><td><input type="text" name="' + cnt + '3"></td></tr>');
        element_id = cnt + '1';
        alert(element_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../modal/system_operator/get_companyexpenses_type.php",
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (json) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                length = result.len;
                for (k = 1; k <= length; k++) {
                    $('#' + element_id + ' option').last().after('<option value="' + eval("result.row" + k + ".company_expenses_type_id") + '">' + eval("result.row" + k + ".company_expenses_type") + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    get_company_expenses_type(cnt + '1');
    $("#anc_rem").click(function () {
        if (cnt > 1) {
            cnt--;
            $("input[id=rows]").val(cnt);
            $('#tbl1 tr:last-child').remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Please add you working code or create fiddle or add snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `dataType` from html to json.

```
dataType: "html",
```

to

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: that's not problem.bcoz data is retriving for first row.